Computing squares on a slide rule without an A or B scale
I've just realised that the Pickett N4 slide rule does not have the A or B scales (which contain $x^2$, where $x$ is the reading on the C and D scales), as per this virtual simulation:
https://sliderulemuseum.com/VirtualSR/n4es/virtual-n4es.shtml
The N4 does have a pair of square root scales for $\sqrt x$ and $\sqrt(10*x)$ (along the bottom of the rule), so given $x$ you can always square it by looking it up on the square root scale and looking up the corresponding entry on the D scale.
But what if I've computed a value $x$ and I'm on the D scale.  I don't see how to transfer it to the square root scale to square it.  If there were an A scale it would be easy; just use the cursor and look it up.  Like here
https://sliderulemuseum.com/VirtualSR2/react/faber_castell_2_83n.shtml
$3$ on the D scale is directly below $9$ on the A scale. Simple!
What am I missing?  Is there a simple way to get the effect of the A scale on a slide rule like the Pickett N4?
Thank you.

Those a cool simulations by the way!

Yes, I agree, they are really good.  There's also something deeply ironic about simulating a slide rule on a computer.

I have to agree. That is actually hilarious. Think about what precision of computation it requires representing it on the screen

I am not sure this is what you want, but I can give you an example of how the C and D scale can work in tandem to get at the problem:
You generally want to multiply a value on the D-scale by itself. You can multiply any number on the D-scale by any number on the C-scale within the range they share, by doing as follows:

We want to find $xy$ by combining C and D
Move the slider to have $C=1$ aligned with $D=x$
This means $C=1$ corresponds to $D=1\cdot x$
Find $C=y$
Read $D=xy$ directly below $C=y$

To square something, just use $x=y$. You can even measure the distance of $1$ to $x$ on the $D$-scale and use that measure to find $1$ to $x$ on the $C$-scale when squaring.

By the way, I am not an expert on slide rules, but this is my best bet right now.

Thank you for this.  You're right that it's possible to compute $x^2$ by computing $x*x$.  This requires, as you outline, sliding the slide of the slide rule.
The point of the A scale is to compute $x^2$ without moving the slide of the slide rule; you just follow the hairline of the cursor from $x$ on the D scale, to the A scale; it will display $x^2$.  Every other slide rule I know of has this feature, including other slide rules by Pickett, like the N3.  But (apparently!) not the N4.
It seems to me that I must be missing something ...
